# Converting a pandas dataframe to a tensor flow dataset - Binary text classification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, text-classification, bert-language-model

I am fairly new to tensor flow and I am trying to train a BERT model for a binary classification task.

I have a data set in a single CSV file that looks like this:

| Description | Target |
| --- | --- |
| This text passed | 1 |
| This text failed | 0 |

I loaded the data set as a pandas data frame.
The guide I am using is the official tensorflow guide I found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert).

The guide uses the IMDb dataset that is structured in separate folders.
This is the code block that created the TensorFlow dataset:

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
batch_size = 32
seed = 42

raw_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    seed=seed)

class_names = raw_train_ds.class_names
train_ds = raw_train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='validation',
    seed=seed)

val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/test',
    batch_size=batch_size)

test_ds = test_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

My question: is there a way to convert my Pandas dataframe into the same format?
I.e How do I generate train_ds, test_ds, and val_ds from a pandas data frame?

Comment: Splitting the data between training, validation and test set is not a matter of format. The standard method would be to split randomly using predefined proportions. You have two choices: either you prepare the dataset into these 3 directories so that you can re-use the same code, or you feed the text yourself.

Comment: @Erwan , I am currently using option 1, by preparing the data into directories.  Could you elaborate on feeding the text myself? I am very new to this. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not familiar with TensorFlow so I don't know in this case but usually there are various methods to provide the input data to the model, probably the "by directory" method is one of several options.